# Mapping UITextField to class property

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, nsobject

my problem is that i have a screen with a lot of UITextField and class where in all the data entered in UITextField is stored in my xyz class. Right now I am mapping my UITextField to the class properties using  switch case which is lot horrible not to mention validation which adds more complexity to it. Is there any way to map the class property with the UITextField and get rid of the switch case, please help.

Comment: You seem to be looking for `IBOutlet`s

Comment: nielsbot has got my question/problem right

Comment: Are you looking for something on lines of Cocoa bindings?

Comment: somewhat but cocoa bindings is not available on iPhone(correct me if wrong)

Comment: Yeah it isn't there but was trying to understand your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Give each text field a tag from 0 to n. You can then use an array to map view tags to <strike>outlet</strike> property names, for example:

```
@interface MyClass

@property ( nonatomic, retain ) id property1 ;
@property ( nonatomic, retain ) id property2 ;
@property ( nonatomic, retain ) id property3 ;

@end
```

Then in your `-(void)textFieldDidChangeText:(NSNotification*)note` (or wherever you are handling your text field changes) method do this:

```
static NSString * fieldNames[] = { @"property1", @"property2", @"property3" } ;
UITextField * field = [ note object ] ;
[ self setValue:field.text forKey:fieldNames[ field.tag ] ] ;
```

Maybe someone else can some up with a more solid solution. HTH

Comment: right basically the problem lies with mapping text field to a property directly and as such adds a need for a string array :( and a wrong index can cause damage.

Comment: You could add this: `assert field.tag > 0 && field.tag < (sizeof(fieldNames)/sizeof(fieldNames[0]))` :-)

Comment: Also, in that case I'd assign tag to a local var to avoid calling field.tag 3x. (`NSInteger tag = field.tag`)

Answer (score 1):

You could consider a class which adopts `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol and contains a string.

```
@interface XXBoundString: NSObject <UITextFieldDelegate> {
    NSString *string;

    ... // Other necessary ivars
}

... // string methods that you want exposed
@end
```

This way you can put all the code in this object. If the validation methods differ per text field, you could accept the code as a block object.

```
-(void)setValidationBlock:(ValidationBlock)block;
```

Here you would replace `NSString`s with `XXBoundString` objects and set each of them to be a delegate of a particular UITextField.